# React Native - Scrollview vertical with scrollview horizontal in it?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm creating an APP to show points of interest of monuments. Right now I'm rendering the information on a ScrollView (vertical way). The output is like this:

[I edited the image, it continues, but I think you get the point.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOWRl.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                <ScrollView>
                    {monumento.pois.map((poi, index) => (
                            <View key={index} style={{marginBottom: 15}} >
                                <Tile
                                    imageSrc = {{uri:poi.image}}
                                    contentContainerStyle = {{marginBottom: -30}}
                                />
                                <View style={styles.map}>
                                    <Icon
                                      raised
                                      reverse
                                      name='location-on'
                                      color='#075e54'
                                      size={36}
                                      onPress={() => navigate('Mapa', {monumento: monumento})} />
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                                    <Text style={styles.titleText}>{poi.name}</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.bodyContent}>
                                    <Text style={styles.bodyText}>{poi.description}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>

        </View>
    );
```

What I want is to scroll normally for one Point of Interest (PoI), but the next PoI I want him to appear by scrooling horizontal (swiping left)...like this:

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXZo7.jpg)

How can I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: i think you should use a swiper. have a look at this https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Comment: you can make scrollview horizontal scroll: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#horizontal

Comment: @Coyote that works! Thank you very much!